# P6Spy does not log hibernate update with HSQLDB

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb, p6spy

I'm trying to set up a simple project using HSQLDB to explain Hibernate basics.
For a better understanding of Hibernate internal's I would like to install P6Spy to show corresponding SQL statements.

I can't get SQL Update statements in my console.

```
Hibernate: insert into User (id, name) values (null, ?)
1505546078019|0|statement|connection 0|insert into User (id, name) values (null, ?)|insert into User (id, name) values (null, 'A')
Hibernate: update User set name=? where id=?
1505546078027|0|commit|connection 0||
```

> P6Spy and Hibernate show me the insert statement, but only Hibernate displays the update statement

Here is my source code :

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6SpyDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:p6spy:hsqldb:mem:so</property>
        <property name="connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>

        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**com/so/User.java**

```
package com.so;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column
    private String name;

    public User() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    protected void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }

}
```

**com/so/Main**

```
package com.so;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

public class Main {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
        User e = new User();
        e.setName("A");
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(e);
        e.setName("B");
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
    }

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            return new AnnotationConfiguration()
                    .addAnnotatedClass(User.class)
                    .configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.so</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate uses slf4j for logging, for our purposes here use the simple 
            backend -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>p6spy</groupId>
            <artifactId>p6spy</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**spy.properties**

```
appender=com.p6spy.engine.spy.appender.StdoutLogger
```

Comment: Not what you are asking, but you get get HSQLDB to log all the executed SQL http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/management-chapt.html#mtc_internal_monitoring

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem. For me it was because hibernate added the updates into a batch and by default batch calls are not logged in p6spy. Update the p6spy properties, so batch is logged.

spy.properties

```
#list of categories to exclude: error, info, batch, debug, statement,
#commit, rollback and result are valid values
#excludecategories=
excludecategories=info,debug,result
```

Answer (score 0):

In Spring data JPA comment this line

```
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=10
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).